# Shell Sort don't working on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, shellsort

I have an code in Java and it works perfect, but the code translated to JavaScript throw an error. The ShellSort method pass a Array to the method.(**I am using the console to debug**) My code is:

```
this.shellSort = function(nums)
    {
//O contador de tempo inicia aqui
    var tempoSS = new Date();
    var n = nums.length;
    console.log("n = ",n);
    var h = n / 2;
    console.log("h = ",h);
    var c, j;
    while (h > 0)
    {
        for (var i = h; i < n; i++)
        {
            c = nums[i];
            j = i;
            while (j >= h && nums[j - h] > c)
            {
                nums[j] = nums[j - h];
    console.log("nums["+j+"] = ",nums[j]);
                j = j - h;
    console.log("j = ",j);
            }
            nums[j] = c;
    console.log("nums["+j+"] = ",nums[j]);
        }
        h = h / 2;
    console.log("h = ",h);
    }
```

the error is caught is `--
[13:52:59.581] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property nums[(j - h)] @ file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/erickribeiro/Desktop/www/index.html:240`

**Test page: dev.erickribeiro.com.br/index.html**

The full script is the html page.
What is wrong?

Comment: I do hope that it is for sport you are implementing this. For any practical purpose there is little reason not to use the native JavaScript `sort` method.

Comment: Yes, it is a homage to my friend of the college. She moved to Russia and I will show the she our work tranlated to JavaScript :D. I kept the indentetaion/comments and variable names used in our work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting stuck in an endless loop because `h` may be a float sometimes. You have to ensure it's an integer (which in Java it is always, since you probably declared it as such):

```
this.shellSort = function(nums)
    {
//O contador de tempo inicia aqui
    var tempoSS = new Date();
    var n = nums.length;
    console.log("n = ",n);

    // HERE:
    var h = Math.floor(n / 2);

    console.log("h = ",h);
    var c, j;
    while (h > 0)
    {
        for (var i = h; i < n; i++)
        {
            c = nums[i];
            j = i;
            while (j >= h && nums[j - h] > c)
            {
                nums[j] = nums[j - h];
    console.log("nums["+j+"] = ",nums[j]);
                j = j - h;
    console.log("j = ",j);
            }
            nums[j] = c;
    console.log("nums["+j+"] = ",nums[j]);
        }

        // AND HERE:
        h = Math.floor(h / 2);
    console.log("h = ",h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your console.log outputs hinted me on this one.